# Using MVC with multiple different databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have used MVC thus far in a traditional EF sense by creating POCO first objects and then adding this to a database context but I have a new problem in that I am trying to recreate a legacy system but using the MVC framework but it uses a connection to multiple different databases and tables.

In the legacy solution they use Enterprise library to create the link to databases but I am not sure that this is the best option available and was wondering what are the options open for dbconext in regards to different database connections at the same time, is this possible?

Comment: Could you provide a few access pattern examples?  For example: Are you typically hitting multiple databases with one request?

Comment: MVC doesn't know *anything* about databases.  The only thing that connects to databases as your describing is Entity Framework.  I suggest you change your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is nothing to do with MVC. Besides, ASP.Net MVC (Presentation Layer) should not even need to know about what kind of ORM or database at Data Access Layer.

Back to original question, it is not worth using Entity Framework, if you have to query two databases at the same time.

I suggest you want to look at other ORM like Dapper.

Comment: Thanks Win sorry for the confusion in the question dont think I put it very elequoently

Comment: @Jay  I would suggest use nhibernate ORM